# how does dynamic linker resolve references in run time?

Tags: linux, c, gcc

let's say I have a source file `dll.c` that use `dlopen` and `dlsym` functions to load a shared library called `F.so` in run time.

`dll.c` has a reference to `some_function()`, and `F.so` has the definition of `some_function()`.

and let's say the picture below is the executable object `prog` which is obtained by

```
linux> gcc -rdynamic -o prog dll.c -ldl
```

[image]

so `.text` section contains the reference of `some_function()` that needs to be resolved when the porgram load `F.so` and start to call `some_function()`

My questions are:

1. It seems to me that the `.text` section(where `some_function()` belongs to) in RAM(executable is copied into memory) needs to be modified by the dynamic linker so that the reference of `some_function()` can be resolved, is my understanding correct?
2. If the  dynamic linker needs to modify the `.text` section in RAM, how does it do it? from my understanding, `.text` section is read-only segment in RAM, how can a read-only segment be modified if it is called read-only?

Comment: Multiply posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/63708380/340790 .  This account has also multiply posted several questions posted by another account that is a prolific multi-poster.

Answer (score 4):

Two features of ELF are missing from your diagram and are used for dynamic linking: the global offset table (GOT) and the procedure linkage table (PLT). The GOT is a table of offsets used for a variety of purposes, and the PLT is a table of procedure stubs used for indirect jumps. The GOT is typically read-write; the PLT can be either read-write, or read-only (and then backed by GOT entries or a separate PLT-specific GOT).

This allows the dynamic linker to update symbol addresses without touching read-only data.

Some older binaries require modifying relocation data in read-only segments; this isn’t a problem for the dynamic linker, but it does mean that the corresponding areas of memory can no longer be shared among processes in memory.

See [How to Write Shared Libraries](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) for details.

Answer (score 2):

#### A.1

Depending on the cpu, the code in the `.text` section for calling the `some_function()` will be some kind of indirect call. It will compute the address at runtime, possibly caching the result for efficiency. This allows the `.text` to be unchanged and therefore it can be shared. The code is usually very slightly bigger and slower.

#### A.2

The assumption is false, so this question doesn't arise. However there is nothing stopping the kernel making a copy of a page of memory and giving it different read/write/execute properties and mapping the new page in at the same address. This can be done for example by the `ptrace` system call and is used by debuggers to plant software breakpoints.